# Should I use Job Scheduler or a Service

Tags: java, android, android-service, android-jobscheduler

Im making this movies database app and I thought that maybe having an API call everytime the activity is created is very expensive for the user. So I thought maybe I should only do one API call per day because there arent lots of movies which are releasing every 10 minutes. So should I use a Job Scheduler or something else like a Service? Im not very advanced in android development . Im good enough to look at codes and understand them. Can you guys guide me in this with some sample code using Job scheduler or something? Thanks guys.

Comment: A service would just work fine on this

Comment: The two are completely independent.  You use a Service when you need some code to run beyond the lifecycle of an Activity.  You use a JobScheduler or Alarm when you need to be notified at some time in the future.  One is not a replacement for the other.  Its actually not unusual for a Service to set up a JobScheduler, or for a JobScheduler to start a Service.